# Accessing"local data" with mplcursors

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplcursors

I have trouble understanding how `mplcursors` cursors work. Let me give an example.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
%matplotlib qt5

def random_data(rows_count):
    data = []
    for i in range(rows_count):
        row = {}
        row["x"] = np.random.uniform()
        row["y"] = np.random.uniform()
        if (i%2 == 0):
            row["type"] = "sith"
            row["color"] = "red"
        else:
            row["type"] = "jedi"
            row["color"] = "blue"
        data.append(row)
    return pd.DataFrame(data)

data_df = random_data(30)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax = plt.gca()

types = ["jedi","sith"]

for scat_type in types:
    local_data_df = data_df.loc[data_df["type"] == scat_type]
    scat = ax.scatter(local_data_df["x"],
               local_data_df["y"],
               c=local_data_df["color"],
               label=scat_type)
    cursor = mplcursors.cursor(scat, hover=mplcursors.HoverMode.Transient)
    @cursor.connect("add")
    def on_add(sel):
        annotation = (local_data_df.iloc[sel.index]["type"]+
                      "\n"+str(local_data_df.iloc[sel.index]["x"])+
                      "\n"+str(local_data_df.iloc[sel.index]["y"]))
        sel.annotation.set(text=annotation)

ax.legend()
plt.title("a battle of Force users")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.xlim(-1, 2)
plt.ylim(-1, 2)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

This code is supposed to generate a DataFrame such that each row has random properties `x`, `y`, a `type` which is `jedi` or `sith`, and a `color` which is `blue` or `red`, depending on if the row is a `jedi` or a `sith`, then scatterplot the jedis in their color, attach to them a cursor, and then scatterplot the siths in their color, and attach to them another cursor, and display a legend box telling the reader that blue points correspond to `jedi` rows and red ones to `sith` ones.
However, when hovering points, the annotations say that all the points are `sith` and the coordinates do not look good.

**I would like to understand why the code does not do what I would like it to do.**

Just to clarify: I call `.scatter()` for each type (`jedi` or `sith`) and then try to attach a cursor to each of the plots because I have tried calling `scatter` on the whole `data_df`, but then the `.legend()` does not display what I want.

**I hope that the answer you give me will be enough for me to be able to write a code that displays the `jedi` and the `sith` points, shows the right annotations and the right legend box.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of strange things going on.

One of the confusions is that having the variable `local_data_df` inside a `for` loop would create a variable that would only be local to one cycle of the loop. Instead, it is just a global variable that gets overridden for each cycle. Similarly, defining the function `on_add` inside the `for` loop doesn't make it local. Also `on_add` will be global and overridden by each cycle of the `for` loop.

Another confusion is that the connected function would have access to local variables from another function or loop. Instead, such local variables get inaccessible once the function or loop has finished.

Further, not that `sel.index` will not be the index into the dataframe, but into the points of the scatter plot. You can reset the index of the "local df" to have it similar to the way `sel.index` is ordered.

To mimic your local variable, you can add extra data to the `scat` object.  E.g. `scat.my_data = local_df` will add that variable to the global object that contains the scatter element (the `PathCollection` that contains all information matplotlib needs to represent the scatter points). Although the variable `scat` gets overridden, there is one `PathCollection` for each of the calls to `ax.scatter`. (You can also access these via `ax.collections`).

Here is a rewrite of your code, trying to stay as close as possible to the original:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

def random_data(rows_count):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.uniform(0, 1, rows_count),
                       'y': np.random.uniform(0, 1, rows_count),
                       'type': np.random.choice(['sith', 'jedi'], rows_count)})
    df['color'] = df['type'].replace({'sith': 'red', 'jedi': 'blue'})
    return df

def on_add(sel):
    local_data_df = sel.artist.my_data
    annotation = (local_data_df.iloc[sel.index]["type"] +
                  "\n" + str(local_data_df.iloc[sel.index]["x"]) +
                  "\n" + str(local_data_df.iloc[sel.index]["y"]))
    sel.annotation.set(text=annotation)

data_df = random_data(30)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

types = ["jedi", "sith"]

for scat_type in types:
    local_data_df = data_df.loc[data_df["type"] == scat_type].reset_index() # resetting the index is necessary
    scat = ax.scatter(local_data_df["x"],
                      local_data_df["y"],
                      c=local_data_df["color"],
                      label=scat_type)
    scat.my_data = local_data_df # store the data into the scat object
    cursor = mplcursors.cursor(scat, hover=mplcursors.HoverMode.Transient)
    cursor.connect("add", on_add)

ax.legend()
ax.set_title("a battle of Force users")
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_xlim(-1, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 2)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors with "local data"]

Answer (score 0):

I really like the answer of JohanC, but I have two cosmetic suggestions that might help others arriving to this page:

- Using groupby to loop over the types
- Using a dictionary for styling to keep data and figure markup separated

The updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

def random_data(rows_count):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.uniform(0, 1, rows_count),
                       'y': np.random.uniform(0, 1, rows_count),
                       'type': np.random.choice(['sith', 'jedi'], rows_count)})
    return df

def on_add(sel):
    locdf = sel.artist.my_data
    annotation = (locdf.iloc[sel.index]["type"] +
                  "\n" + str(locdf.iloc[sel.index]["x"]) +
                  "\n" + str(locdf.iloc[sel.index]["y"]))
    sel.annotation.set(text=annotation)

data_df = random_data(30)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

styledict = {'sith': dict(c='red', marker='o'),
             'jedi': dict(c='blue', marker='s')}

for scat_type, data in data_df.groupby('type'):
    scat = ax.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], label=scat_type, **styledict[scat_type])
    scat.my_data = data
    cursor = mplcursors.cursor(scat, hover=mplcursors.HoverMode.Transient)
    cursor.connect("add", on_add)

ax.legend()
ax.set_title("a battle of Force users")
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_xlim(-1, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 2)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
```